# Web application using JSP web application or applet?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, coding-style

If i want to make a web application in java i mean **JSP** should I create an Applet and put it into a browser or create "Java web project"?
In other words the big companies system like Oracal and others have there own system by creating java web application or using applet and putting it into browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a "Java web project".

Using an [applet](/questions/tagged/applet) is considered a bad practice due to all of the [security issues](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-032A), the need for the user to install the correct version of [java](/questions/tagged/java), and [enable it in the browser](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml).

Go with a solid java web framework like [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) / [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc).  See this guide on how to start: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: Thanks a lot you really helped me

Comment: @AhmedEssam , if my answer worked for you can you [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it?

Answer (score 0):

Java Applet runs on client side (in the brouser, like javascript), but JSP is part of Java Servlet API and runs on server side (you need to install servlet container like [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) to run them). It's not equivalent technologies with different abilities and application area.

Comment: yes but applet is not likely to be used anymore right?

Comment: Applets aren't  popular, but in rare cases, they are still used. For example, i saw them in the internet banking system.

Answer (score 0):

Applets are old fashioned now, Applets were used to create interactive web applications in the early days of http development when developing a interactive website was not possible using any browser based technologies like html, css and java script.

But now the things have changed with the evolution of [web-2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0). Now you can develop the interactive web application by using only browser based technologies and you don't have to install any third party tools or plugins like in the case of applet, JRE should be installed on client machine.

Comment: Then if i need to create a system to a company that use servers then i need to create "java web project" right?